# List forms (new/edit/view) not appearing in popup

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, modal-dialog

We have deployed a SP2013 site via powershell and notice that the list forms do not open in popups rather they open as page.

We created a new SP site via central admin SharePoint UI, Same problem.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the reason can be but the setting can be eenabled from list settings page

Comment: Yes, List settings -> Advanced Settings -> Under "Dialogs" -> "Launch forms in a dialog?" --> this was set as 'NO'

Comment: Do you think when we create list via powershell we have to explicitly enable the diaglogs?

Comment: Yes looks like it happens during migrationhttp://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19185.sharepoint-2013-how-to-open-list-forms-in-dialog-box-instead-of-navigating-to-another-page.aspx

Comment: I just created a web app and site via SharePoint Central admin UI. Same issue this setting is by default as 'NO'. Looks like this is a default behavior for SP2013.

Comment: Nadeem, are you aware of powershell code to turn this ON. I am planning to execute it as soon as the list is created.

Comment: SPList.NavigateForFormsPages = $false should do the trick.