# How to enable Modal Dialog for All List forms (new/display/edit) via PowerShell?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

We have deployed a SP2013 site via powershell and notice that the list forms do not open in popups rather they open as page.

Is it possible via powershell to update all lists so that the new/edit/display forms open up in modal dialog?

Foll. is code provided by [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91249/list-forms-new-edit-view-not-appearing-in-popup) Nadeem@Forum to enable it for 1 list:-

```
SPList.NavigateForFormsPages = $false
```

I guess it must be =$true, isnt it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `SPList.NavigateForFormsPages = $false` is correct. See this for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.navigateforformspages.aspx

> A Boolean value = true indicates navigate the full page and false
>   indicates that the list form page is launched in a modal dialog.

Here is an example of doing it for lists in a given web.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://aissp2013:111
foreach ($list in $web.Lists)
{
    $list.NavigateForFormsPages = $false;               
    $list.Update(); 
}
```

Comment: Hi Nadeem, can you give me some reference links where I can get powershell basics please. For example: iterating lists, getting item values..

Comment: If you are able to right Server object model code in C#, then you should not find it difficult to learn PowerShell for SharePoint. Here in this example, I get list item attachments using Powershell and C#. See how similar they look. http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2013/08/get-sharepoint-list-item-attachments.html